# How to iterate over categories and get all the names for submenu?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I trying create a sidebar, where the first level will be the categories and submenu will be the names.

DB schema

```
  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "niche"
    t.string   "category"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Controller

```
def index
@product = Product.group(:category)
end
```

View

```
<% @product.each do |t| %>
 <li>
  <a href="javascript:;">
  <span class="title"><%= t.category %></span>
  </a>
 </li>
<% end %>
```

For now I am able to loop through all available categories, but how can I get the "niche" from each category and display in submenu?

Comment: Try `<%= t.category.niche %>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= @product.each do |product| %>
   <%= content_tag :li do %>
      <%= product.category %>
      <%  Product.where(category: product.category).pluck(:niche).distinct.each do |niche| %>
         <%= niche %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This will answer your question directly.

Whilst you could probably get the SQL working with one query (using a [self join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-self-joins.htm)), it will be far more beneficial to have `categories` as its own table.

--

> how can I get the "niche" from each category and display in submenu?

What you're asking can be fixed with the proper [associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html).

Currently, you're writing `category` as a pure string inside the `products` table. There is nothing wrong with this, but will prevent you from adding any extra functionality ([extensibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility)).

I would use a [`has_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association) relationship binding the `product` and `category` models together. I can then [make a hierarchy](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree) within the `product` model to denote "niche":

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | category_id | name | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :category
end

#app/models/category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
   # columns id | name | parent_id | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :products
   acts_as_tree
end
```

This will allow me to do the following:

```
@categories = Category.all
@categories.each do |category|
   category.children.each do |niche| #-> niches
      niche.name #-> this will be a category also
      niche.products.each do |product|
         product.name #-> product is a member object with "Product" model data
      end
   end
end
```

---

**Update**

Here's how you can add the category at `Product` save:

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
   before_create: :assign_category

   private

   def assign_category
      self.category_id = Category.find_By name: self.category
   end
end
```

Comment: As I am saving the data from sax parsing, I am getting the table data by default(saved category as string inside Products table). Are there any methods to separate them to a Category table easily?

Comment: Currently, my method is to write a `after create` method to Product model, and save category_id according to the category data everytime a new product is created. An example like this `self.update(category_id: Category.where("name = ?", self.category).first.id)`. Will there be any problems with this method?

Comment: Well it adds a level of recursion which will hurt efficiency. You're almost there - just populate the `category_id` before you save your model (I've written an update)

Answer (score 0):

According to your schema "niche" is an attribute on a product.
So you'll have to do something like this `<%= t.niche %>`.

If you'd like to have this on category level, you'll have to create a logical association. Something like a product has_many categories and make niche an attribute on the categories table.

(For reference also see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Comment: Agreed, the structure you have is not correct for what you are doing.  You can do something like this Product.where(category: @product.category).pluck(:niche) but this is ugly.  I do not condone this at all.